# What are the names of the seven sages in the Epic of Gilgamesh

Tags: gilgamesh

The Dictionary of Deities and Demons states that:
Based on a tradition that goes back to the 3rd millennium, the term apkallu is used for legendary creatures endowed with wisdom, seven in number, who existed before the flood.

Can anyone tell me the names of the seven legendary creatures endowed with wisdom, please!